# Most elegant way to create request and delegate it based on two variables

Tags: java

I've object with two string

```
public class Foo {
    String firstCondition;
    String secondCondition;
    //...//
}
```

These types may alternately be empty, but based whether they will be empty or not properly want to delegate to specific method.

I think solution as presented bellow is pretty uggly.

```
if(firstCondition !=null && secondCondition!= null){
methodA();
}

if(firstCondition !=null && secondCondition == null){
methodB();
}

if(firstCondition ==null && secondCondition!= null){
methodC();
}
if(firstCondition ==null && secondCondition== null){
methodD();
}
```

I am not loking for ready implementation, but perhaps for some pattern what to do in such case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change the types of     String firstCondition 
    String secondCondition to boolean? That would make things  much easier:)

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't have any issue with the 4 logical checks, you probably should do it this way.  But, we can make it more terse as follows:

```
int flag1 = Objects.isNull(firstCondition) ? 0 : 1;
int flag2 = Objects.isNull(secondCondition) ? 0 : 1;

if (flag1 * flag2 == 1) {
    methodA();
}
else if (flag1 + flag2 == 0) {
    methodD();
}
else if (flag1 == 1 && flag2 == 0) {
    methodB();
}
else {
    methodC();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the ternary operator, not a bad way to do null checks and cuts down on some code. (Although I know some people aren't fans of nested ternaries).

Just offering another idea :)

```
(firstCondition != null && secondCondition != null) ? methodA() :
(firstCondition != null && secondCondition == null) ? methodB() :
(firstCondition == null && secondCondition != null) ? methodC() :
(firstCondition == null && secondCondition == null) ? methodD();
```

If you want to stick with your way of doing it though I would recommend you use some else if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 11 you can leverage `Optional.ifPresentOrElse` like so:

```
        String firstCondition = null;
        String secondCondition = null;

        Optional.ofNullable(firstCondition)
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        condition1 -> Optional.ofNullable(secondCondition)
                                .ifPresentOrElse(
                                        condition2 -> {
                                            //methodA();
                                        },
                                        () -> {
                                            //methodB();
                                        }),
                        () -> Optional.ofNullable(secondCondition)
                                .ifPresentOrElse(
                                        condition2 -> {
                                            //methodC();
                                        },
                                        () -> {
                                            //methodD();
                                        }));
```

This gives you access to `Consumers` based on whether the `Optional` value was present or not. Chaining these you can reach all of the cases in your example above. Of course this would not be an ideal solution for many inputs as the code is already a touch unsightly.